# Codeigniter on localhost(Xampp) keeps redirecting to https://www.localhost:1234/

Tags: codeigniter, url, redirect, view

I am trying to enter urls relating to files in a codeigniter application using the given format, but everytime I do it with my current project (which is a live project, sitting inside a now downloaded folder called public_html) it keeps redirecting to https://www.localhost:1234/ (my local host is localhost:1234) instead of opening the view.

I have other codeigniter projects on the localhost which work fine.

e.g. I Have a codeigniter blog called ciblog and on entering this, referring to the controllers and function inside that controller, it opens the view **correctly:**

```
localhost:1234/ciblog/index.php/welcome/index
```

In the above example, ciblog is the name of the folder in which the whole project sits.

however, when I try to do the same for my other site for which the folder is public_html, I enter:

```
localhost:1234/public_html/index.php/home/index
```

where home is the controller and index is the function, it keeps **redirecting to this (with a https)**

```
https://www.localhost:1234/index.php/home/index
```

I have deleted the .htaccess file, so it can't be that. What else can it be?

The original contents of the .**htaccess file** are below:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# force ssl
RewriteCond     %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule     ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

I've looked at other question and answers that appear to be asking something similar, but none contain a solution.

File path screenshot shown below, if that is of any help

[Screenshot of home controller, showing structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yh746.png)

Comment: what about  base_url

Comment: Can you show us the config.php file ?